# java FileNotFoundException on AWS EC2 Linux 2 but file is there

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, filenotfoundexception

A certain method call in my .jar file (a java input for an Apache Flink cluster) breaks with the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/ec2-user/realFile.csv (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
        at org.apache.flink.core.fs.local.LocalDataInputStream.<init>(LocalDataInputStream.java:50)
        at org.apache.flink.core.fs.local.LocalFileSystem.open(LocalFileSystem.java:142)
        at org.apache.flink.api.common.io.FileInputFormat$InputSplitOpenThread.run(FileInputFormat.java:996)
```

As the title says, the file is definitively at that path, to double-check I have run the method on a file that is actually not there, and noticed that, while the exception type is the same, the stack trace is noticeable different.

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File fakeFile.csv does not exist or the user running Flink ('ec2-user') has insufficient permissions to access it.
        at org.apache.flink.core.fs.local.LocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(LocalFileSystem.java:115)
        at org.apache.flink.api.common.io.FileInputFormat.createInputSplits(FileInputFormat.java:588)
        at org.apache.flink.api.common.io.FileInputFormat.createInputSplits(FileInputFormat.java:62)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionJobVertex.<init>(ExecutionJobVertex.java:273)
        ... 22 more
```

To add even more certainty I have modified the java file to explicitly check File.exists() before opening it and it works as expected. fakeFile.csv comes up as not existing, while realFile passes that programmatic check. I checked that the realFile has good permissions

```
ls -l realFile.csv
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ec2-user ec2-user 8 Jan 14 22:22 realFile.csv
```

Despite that, I feel like there must be some fencing or permission issues going on. I compiled the jar on the machine where I am running it, and I had tried it earlier in a different environment with no issues.

Comment: You can check to see not only if it exists, but also if it is readable as well. It may not be readable due to permissions or if it’s a symlink to something elsewhere; it’s not enough to just check if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, it turns out Apache flink was trying to open the file in one of the slave machines and of course was not finding it there. I replicated the input file on all machines and it worked, although flink seems to be picking input from arbitrary machines and dropping the output to arbitrary machines. This is certainly not how reading from disk is supposed to be like, but at least now I know the problem.

To summarise:

- when I run the code with fakeFile.csv I got FileNotFound on the local machine because while building the flink job, the file was clearly not there
- when I run the code with realFile.csv, I pass that part but get FileNotFound durig the job execution itself because Flink had decided to make some random slave machine open the file

To generalise:
Even though with my two tests I got the same exception type, I should have started looking much earlier at the possibility that the exceptions were fired at different stages of the program lifecycle.